# Looking for PHP-like str_replace() for C/C++ but WITHOUT malloc()/realloc(), using the original buffer

Tags: c, str-replace

I was looking for a [PHP-like **str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for C/C++, but I found only solutions which allocate/reallocate buffer for the result. In embedded environment, it's not always possible, there are no memory for strings or there's even no *malloc()*. So I'm looking for a function, which use the same buffer, similar to *strncat()*, where the max. buffer size is given as parameter:

```
 void str_replace(char* search,char* replace,char* subject,int maxBufferSize);
```

The trick is, that I've just written one, which I will post within a minute. Yes, this is the typical case of answering my own question, but [I've read that it's legal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).

Anyway, I will push accept button on the best answer. My solution is tested and hopefully works well, but there is room for improvement. There will be a better answer, I am sure. I can wait.

Comment: The whole C/C++ thing splits the path and takes some focus away. C++ has `std::replace`.

Comment: I need to deal with byte buffers (aka. char*), not objects.

Comment: Should replacing "abc" with "ab" in the string "abcc" result in "abc" or "ab"?

Comment: @chris: `std::replace` won't work here. It can replace only single entries (in this case characters).

Comment: @BillyONeal, Oh good point. It's still possible with `std::string` members or `boost::replace_all` :)

Comment: @chris: `std::string` assumes that it'll be able to allocate memory.

Comment: I don't want to use *string*. I think *string* is allocating memory, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try, untested:

```
void str_replace(char *search, char *replace, char *subject, size_t size)
{
    char *end = subject+size;
    size_t sl = strlen(search);
    size_t rl = strlen(replace);
    size_t l = strlen(subject);
    char *src = memmove(end-l-1, subject, l+1);
    char *dest = subject;
    while (*src) {
        char *match = strstr(src, search);
        if (!match) {
            match = src + strlen(src);
            rl = 0;
        }
        memmove(dest, src, match-src);
        dest += match-src;
        src = match+sl;
        memcpy(dest, replace, rl);
        dest += rl;
    }
    *dest = 0;
}
```

This assumes `strlen(replace) <= strlen(search)`. If that constraint is not met, some additional checks are needed to ensure `dest` doesn't pass `src` and that the replacement fits when it's copied into place.

This algorithm should be near-optimal for avoiding excess accesses (reads and writes).

Comment: Replace string can be longer than search string, it's a wild life.

Comment: Fail, *memmove()* allocates extra memory.

Comment: That man page does not mention malloc. `malloc` cannot be used to implement `memmove` bevause `malloc` can fail but `memmove` cannot.

Comment: It says that *"...src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest..."* - so *temporary array* must be allocated somehow. Anyway, if it copies the stuff, it does not differ from solution which allocates memory for result. ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove )

Comment: No, actually it must not. Learn to read 'as though', and preferably read the spec rather than man pages.

Comment: I was surprised, when I read it, because moving a block in memory requires only easy choice: should we run the index *0 to n* or *n downto 0*.

Comment: Of course. Even if it were legal to implement it with `malloc`, nobody would do that because it's inferior to the trivial implementation you just found in all possible ways.

Comment: A much harder challenge is to implement the equivalent of `memmove` on a *circular* buffer without temp space. In that case, it should be obvious that choosing a direction won't help you (since the memory slots involved are no longer ordered). A while back there was a question on that exact topic on SO, and it took quite a while for anybody to develop a complete, correct answer, but it turns out the problem is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's my quick solution. It works, but has issues:

- when the *pattern* is found more than once, the remaining part (shrink/expand) will be copied in each round;
- *memcpy()* should be used;
- some pre-calculations should be done outside the *for* statements.

*EDIT: comments added for request.*

```
    void strReplace(char* pattern,char* replacement,char* buffer,int maxLength) {

      int buflen = strlen(buffer);  // atual string length (changes after each replace)
      int patlen = strlen(pattern);  // pattern length, constant
      int replen = strlen(replacement);  // replacement lengh, constant
      int matlen = (patlen < replen ? patlen : replen);  // length of pattern/replacement mathcing part
      int ptr = 0;  // pointer, runs from 0 to buffer length

      while (true) {

        // find out, if string at buffer[ptr] matches the pattern
        int match = true;
        for (int n = 0; n < patlen; n++) {
          if ((n + ptr) == buflen) return;
          if (buffer[n + ptr] != pattern[n]) {
            match = false;
            break;
          } // if matching
        } // for pattern

        // if not match, increase ptr
        if (!match) {
          ptr++;
          if (ptr > buflen) return;
          continue;
        } // if not match

        // replace the common part (which requires no remaining block move)
        for (int n = 0; n < matlen; n++) buffer[n + ptr] = replacement[n];
        // if we're lucky, the search string is same lenght as replacement
        if (patlen == replen) return;

        // move remaining
        if (patlen > replen) {  // shrink, if repacement was shorter

          int shrink = patlen - replen;
          // perform shrink
          for (int idx = matlen + ptr; idx < buflen - shrink; idx++) {
            buffer[idx] = buffer[shrink + idx];
          }
          // don't forget to close the asciiz string
          buffer[buflen - shrink] = 0;

          // align ptr
          ptr = 1 + ptr - shrink;
          // align buffer
          buflen -= shrink;

        } else {   // expan if replacement is longer

          int expand = replen - patlen;
          int bufend = buflen + expand;  // buffer end after expand
          if (bufend > maxLength - 1) bufend = maxLength - 1;  // apply maxLength

          // make room by copying remaining to the end of the string
          for (int idx = bufend; idx > ptr + matlen + expand; idx--) {
            buffer[idx - 1] = buffer[idx - 1 - expand];
          }
          // fill the hole with the remainig part of the replacement
          for (int n = matlen; n < replen; n++) {
            buffer[n + ptr] = replacement[n];
          }
          // don't forget to close the asciiz string
          buffer[bufend] = 0;

          // align ptr
          ptr = 1 + ptr + expand;
          // align buffer
          buflen = bufend;

        } // if shrink else expand

        // continue from new ptr

      } // scan buffer

    } // strReplace()
```

Comment: The function signature lacks comments: eg, maxLength is the available space in buffer? what to do when it is not enough? Also, see R. comment. In the body there are lines more like "if ((n + ptr) == buflen) return;" what begs for comments.

Comment: If you're not using `strstr`, this is going to be highly suboptimal (quadratic badness). Optimal `strstr` is `O(n+m)` and hard to reproduce yourself.

Comment: BTW, `memcpy` cannot be used unless you have strong guarantees about excess space. `memmove` is needed.

Comment: Man memmove(3) says: *"copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array"* - it's even worse than allocating a buffer for result.

Comment: The 'as though' gives a fool-proof algorithm that avoids some tricky issues related to comparing pointers from separate arrays (undefined behaviour) — but the double-copy algorithm is 'never' used in operational versions of `memmove()`.